# Why does jackson add an "empty": false, into the Json

Tags: java, jackson

I've annotated a Java class with Jackson

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
  "estimated_shipping_weight",
  "useestimatedweight",
  "matched",
  "available",
  "primary_vendor",
  "stock_status_code",
  "primary_vendor",
  "listprice",
  "webprice",
  "hits",
  "IsIndividual",
  "clearance",
  "display_uom",
  "display_uom_factor",
  "weight",
  "rank",
  "box_qty",
  "ddsFileDateSource",
  "dateLastUpdated",
  "ddiFileDateSource",
  "cost"
})

public class AdditionalFields {

  public static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AdditionalFields.class);
  @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
  @JsonProperty("estimated_shipping_weight")
  private Double estimatedShippingWeight;
  @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
  @JsonProperty("useestimatedweight")
  private String useestimatedweight;
  @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
  @JsonProperty("matched")
  private String matched;
  @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
  @JsonProperty("IsIndividual")
  private String IsIndividual;
  @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
  @JsonProperty("stock_status_code")
  private String stockStatusCode;
  @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
  @JsonProperty("available")
  private Integer available;
  @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
  @JsonProperty("sch_available")
  private String schAvailable;
  @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
  @JsonProperty("primary_vendor")
  private Integer primaryVendor;
  @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
  @JsonProperty("listprice")
  private Double listprice;
  @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
  @JsonProperty("webprice")
  private Double webprice;
  @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
  @JsonProperty("hits")
  private Integer hits;
  @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
  @JsonProperty("clearance")
  private String clearance;
  @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
  @JsonProperty("display_uom_factor")
  private Integer displayUomFactor;
  @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
  @JsonProperty("display_uom")
  private String displayUom;
  @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
  @JsonProperty("weight")
  private Double weight;
  @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
  @JsonProperty("box_qty")
  private Integer boxQty;
  @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
  @JsonProperty("rank")
  private Integer rank;
  @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
  @JsonProperty("product_line_description")
  private String productLineDescription;
  @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
  @JsonProperty("ddiFileDateSource")
  private String ddiFileDateSource;
  @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
  @JsonProperty("ddsFileDateSource")
  private String ddsFileDateSource;
  @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
  @JsonProperty("dateLastUpdated")
  private String dateLastUpdated;
  @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
  @JsonProperty("cost")
  private String cost;
```

However I'm getting an additional field **"empty": false**, in the json output which is unwanted. I'm wondering why that field shows up in the output and how to remove it.

```
   "additional_fields": {
        "matched": "f",
        "available": 0,
        "primary_vendor": 864,
        "listprice": 1364.29,
        "webprice": 1604.414,
        "display_uom": "EA",
        "display_uom_factor": 1,
        "ddiFileDateSource": "DDI_2021_10_06_14_36_37.zip",
        "empty": false,
        "product_line_description": "ABB"
    }
```

Serialization

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY);
String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(additionalFields);
```

Comment: Is `ddsjson` an object of type `AdditionalFields`? If it isn't: can you reproduce this by calling `writeValueAsString(anInstanceOfAdditionalFields)`? If you can't, then you might want to look at (and show us) the place where a field of type `AdditionalFields` is defined.

Comment: It looks like you're not showing us the whole `AdditionalFields` class. Does it by any chance contain the method `boolean isEmpty()`?

Comment: @BambooleanLogic is does contain an isEmpty method. That has no associated json property. How did you know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However I'm getting an additional field "empty": false, in the json
> output which is unwanted. I'm wondering why that field shows up in the
> output and how to remove it.

As an user suggested in his comment this behaviour is due to the fact that Jackson library for the serialization inspects your class and when it finds a method beginning with the prefix *is*, it automatically adds a field in the json file with the name (in this case `empty`) that appears after the prefix *is* and the corresponding value. To avoid this you can annotate your method with [`JsonIgnore`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnore.html).